# Codeigniter check callback at last

Tags: php, codeigniter

To validate any user input in form in codeigniter we use

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'trim|required|min_length[8]|max_length[20]');
```

It works properly
But when we add a callback function

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'trim|required|min_length[8]|max_length[20]|callback_validate_credentials');
```

Then first it check callback is true or not. Suppose User fill password of length 3 then it should give message "**Password must be more than 8 char long**" But  it gives message of callback.

Comment: Try setting validation for custom rules on new line, dont append it with core validation rules or try to append custom validation at first

Comment: @V for Vendetta Stil Same Problem

Comment: Alternative, you can check after validation success at last for your custom validate credentials.I means, don't create custom validation, just write your required code, after validation success to check your custom validation. So your purpose will get solved.

Comment: @V for Vendetta This is working but is this real solution or something like 'jugad'

Comment: Its Jugad !! You can try other way, create your function as core validation rules and check

Comment: you can check this link for your solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30838458/codeigniter-form-validation-rule-for-match-password/30838805